# Bootstrap-like container in Quasar?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, vue.js, quasar-framework

The Quasar website states:

> When using Quasar, you won’t need additional heavy libraries like [...] Bootstrap. It’s got those needs covered internally, and all with a small footprint!

However, I can't find out how to achieve a Bootstrap-container-like behavior in Quasar. I came across the example [here](https://quasar.dev/layout/grid/row#Equal-width) which apparently uses rows and columns like bootstrap, but doesn't have any auto-resizing container element around it.

Does the container not exist in Quasar? Is it not recommended? Or am I just not looking at the right place?

Comment: OP here, this question is getting old and they might have added some layout functionality to the docs. I haven't used Quasar in a while and don't have the time to dig into it, but check https://quasar.dev/layout/layout

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was facing the same issue. I don't think Quasar have this feature, and I ended up having to create my custom CSS for the container.

This is the class that I made inspired by Bootstrap, put this on your `app.scss` (or `app.css`)

```
// breakpoint variable, from https://quasar.dev/style/breakpoints
// Except the xs one because I think 600px is too small
$xs-breakpoint: 718px;
$sm-breakpoint: 1024px;
$md-breakpoint: 1439px;
$lg-breakpoint: 1920px;

.container,
.container-sm,
.container-md,
.container-lg,
.container-xl {
  width: 100%;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}

@media (min-width: $xs-breakpoint) {
  .container,
  .container-sm {
    max-width: 540px;
  }
}

@media (min-width: $sm-breakpoint) {
  .container,
  .container-sm,
  .container-md {
    max-width: 920px;
  }
}

@media (min-width: $md-breakpoint) {
  .container,
  .container-sm,
  .container-md,
  .container-lg {
    max-width: 1140px;
  }
}

@media (min-width: $lg-breakpoint) {
  .container,
  .container-sm,
  .container-md,
  .container-lg,
  .container-xl {
    max-width: 1440px;
  }
}
```

If you are using `.css`, just delete the variable and put the breakpoint value on the `@media min-width` directly

And then use the class

```
<q-page class="container">
    Boo!
</q-page>
```

I also made container classes for different break point. I found this useful when I have different page with different type of content. You can remove other container classes for specific breakpoint if you only need one type of container.

Of course, you can adjust the `max-width` on each breakpoint (or even the breakpoint value, but I won't recommend this) to your liking.

Check the css + html demo [here](https://jsfiddle.net/hcx2snrz/10/)

Comment: Owl - this is great. Assuming you are using scss for your style builds, you could make one change and use `$breakpoint-xs`, `$breakpoint-sm` etc as your variable names then just change the variable value for `$breakpoint-xs` in the `quasar.variables.scss` file to your liking (718px in your example). Doing this would ensure you are always using the same scss variable widths for size through your CSS code. Either way, used your solution - thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Here is the version using quasar breakpoint variables

```scss
// Uncomment to override the default breakpoints
//$breakpoint-xs: 599px
//$breakpoint-sm: 1023px
//$breakpoint-md: 1439px
//$breakpoint-lg: 1919px

@import '~quasar/src/css/variables';

$container-padding: 20px;

.container,
.container-sm,
.container-md,
.container-lg,
.container-xl {
    width: 100%;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
}

@media (min-width: $breakpoint-sm-min) {
    .container,
    .container-sm {
        max-width: $breakpoint-xs - $container-padding;
    }
}

@media (min-width: $breakpoint-md-min) {
    .container,
    .container-sm,
    .container-md {
        max-width: $breakpoint-sm - $container-padding;
    }
}

@media (min-width: $breakpoint-lg-min) {
    .container,
    .container-sm,
    .container-md,
    .container-lg {
        max-width: $breakpoint-md - $container-padding;
    }
}

@media (min-width: $breakpoint-xl-min) {
    .container,
    .container-sm,
    .container-md,
    .container-lg,
    .container-xl {
        max-width: $breakpoint-lg - $container-padding;
    }
}
```